# Creating global class. Error: android.app.application can not be cast to com

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class

I'm trying to create a global class. I want have a global variable for all my activity.

My class:

```
package com.example.app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Application;

public class Records extends Application{

private int N_livelli=30;
private int[] record = new int[N_livelli];
private String path = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/Records.txt";

public void LetturaFile()
{
    File f = new File(path);
    if(f.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            FileReader fileLeggi = new FileReader(path);
            BufferedReader lettore = new BufferedReader(fileLeggi);
            String rigaLetta;
            int n=0;
            while((rigaLetta=lettore.readLine())!=null)
            {
                record[n]=Integer.valueOf(rigaLetta);
                n++;
            }
            lettore.close();
            fileLeggi.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try 
        {
            for(int i=0;i<N_livelli;i++) record[i]=0;
            f.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fileScrivi = new FileWriter(path);
            fileScrivi.write("");
            for(int i=0;i<N_livelli;i++) fileScrivi.append(record[i]+"\n");
            fileScrivi.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public int getRecord(int livello)
{
    return record[livello-1];
}
}
```

My code on OnCreate of MainActivity:

```
[...]
Records records = (Records) getApplicationContext();
records.LetturaFile();
[..]
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.app"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        [...]
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        [...]
    </activity>
 </application>
 <application 
    android:name=".Records">
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Eclipse error: android.app.application can not be cast to com.example.app.Records

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: I would use a preference specifically hold the variable in a sharedPreference  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the ful path of your class in the application tag, and not by adding another application tag with nothing else in it..

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
android:name="com.example.app.Records" >
...
```